# Mac xdebug make warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'jmp_buf *' (aka 'int (*)[37]')

Tags: macos, makefile, xdebug

I get this when I run `make` on xdebug on the Mac (OS X 10.10.2):

```
xdebug_handler_dbgp.c:900:21: warning: 
  incompatible pointer types initializing 'jmp_buf *' (aka 'int (*)[37]')
  with an expression of type 'sigjmp_buf *' (aka 'int (*)[38]')
  [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    jmp_buf           *original_bailout = EG(bailout);
```

The build completes but is there anything to be concerned about with this warning?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and should be fixed, but in this case it seems harmless.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/bfe69665c5ef14ea96f59297301a7ad76a31c544/xdebug_handler_dbgp.c#L900) we see that a pointer (to array of 38 ints) is copied from `bailout` to a temporary variable called `original_bailout` (pointing to array of 37 ints). No operations are performed on that temporary variable and a few lines below the pointer is copied back to the original variable `bailout`.  `original_bailout` is not used any more.

As there is no access to array through incompatible `original_bailout` variable I don’t see any risk of corruption.

The fix could be to replace `jmp_buf` type by `JMP_BUF` macro defined in `Zend/zend.h`:

```
#ifdef HAVE_SIGSETJMP
#       define SETJMP(a) sigsetjmp(a, 0)
#       define LONGJMP(a,b) siglongjmp(a, b)
#       define JMP_BUF sigjmp_buf
#else
#       define SETJMP(a) setjmp(a)
#       define LONGJMP(a,b) longjmp(a, b)
#       define JMP_BUF jmp_buf
#endif
```

So that line 900 reads:

```
JMP_BUF          *original_bailout = EG(bailout);
```